# Finding out where grub writes boot order on disk?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I'm trying to find where grub writes the locations of the boot order at in the disk. What I'm trying to do is to modify the place in memory where the BIOS decide where to boot to first.

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu installed on 2 separate drives. I want to make so that when I reboot from Windows it will automatically boot to Ubuntu and vice versa. I have tried using bcdedit on the windows side and modifying the grub file to set a default OS for my computer to boot to on the Ubuntu side. The problem with doing this is that I would get stuck in an endless loop. The OS will bounce me to the other if I don't make a decision, I need to make this process automatic.

Do you guys have any idea how I can do this?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? But BIOS controls drive order. You can set grub to boot once. You can set UEFI to boot once. Not sure about Windows. Some with BIOS have manually installed grub to a NTFS or FAT32 partition and copied boot stanzas into that grub.cfg. Then they can edit from both Windows & Ubuntu with .bat or .sh files.

Comment: Its BIOS. Yeah I modified the grub and updated the grub.cfg but all that does is pre-select Windows or Ubuntu from the grub menu. I'm trying to make it boot into either windows or ubuntu without making any selection at all. Basically I need to write a script that will change the boot order in BIOS from the desktop of either Windows or Ubuntu.

Comment: Some threads: Boot Windows once:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2309436&p=13423016#post13423016
Reboot grub to different system default
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1310463

Comment: Ok I'll take a look at those scripts. By the way do you know where grub writes the boot order to? When ever I update the grub.cfg something changes in memory that will re-order the boot order right? Where does this happen, I'm looking at the source code for grub but I can't really find where it writes it to yet.

Comment: If BIOS grub nor Windows can change boot order. In UEFI they can. The grub menu controls boot order and you can change settings in etc/default/grub. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen and 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus

Comment: OK so for the first step I should reinstall both OS in UEFI instead of Legacy mode right? Also is there a way to dd the boot order directly?

Comment: I think my OS/2 used to dd MBR back when dual booting it & Windows. You could install Windows boot loader from Windows and grub from Ubuntu. Not sure of commands in Windows to dd grub's copy of MBR. Grub2 does not like to be installed to a partition. But you can -force it and move boot flag back and forth. Windows boot loader only works on active partition in primary partition. But syslinux or lilo boot to all partitions boot sectors.